# (iphone) build for archive, can't find 3rd party library header files. such as boost

Tags: iphone, xcode, include, archive

I'm doing "build for archive" for the first time.

Although I can run app on simulator or device,
When I run "build for archive", xcode complains about missing header files of 3rd party library.

I guess header include path is not correctly set for "archive",
but I've updated to xcode4 today, and can't find where to fix that.

Thank you

Comment: this may sound redundant but did you reset xcode and try again??